# How can I map a "y"/"n" column to Boolean in Scala's Slick?

Tags: string, scala, mapping, boolean, slick

I'm new to Scala and Slick, and I found [this built-in type mapper from AnyType to Boolean](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/0.11.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.BooleanColumnExtensionMethods). I need to map "y" to true and "n" to false, which seems to be simple. Can someone show me how to use it? My current code is like this, re-inventing the wheel:

```
    sealed trait YesNoBoolean
    case object True extends YesNoBoolean
    case object False extends YesNoBoolean

    implicit val boolTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[YesNoBoolean, String](
      { b =>
        assertNotNull(b)
        if(b == True) "y" else "n"
      }, { i =>
        assertNotNull(i)
        if(i == "y") True else False
      }
    )
```

I actually need to map to the real Boolean type. I have several columns that use this nefarious scheme (legacy from PHP).

I think I need to do this in the Table definition:

```
object Record extends Table[(Int,YesNoBoolean)]("record") {
  def is_usable_entry = column[YesNoBoolean]("usable_entry", O.DBType("enum('y','n')"))
...
}
```

Comment: Does [BooleanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html) help?

Comment: Thanks, that's the type of thing, but I probably just need some example code using the library I linked to. The problem is that mapping goes from a user-defined type to a standard type, but I need to go from one standard type to another but have the Slick db column type use that mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def is_usable_entry = column[Boolean]
  ("usable_entry",O.DBType("enum('y','n')"))(
    MappedColumnType.base[Boolean, String](
      if(_) "y" else "n",_=="y"
    )
  )
```

If this does not work you may have to pull out the type mapper and make it implicit. In that case you probably have to exclude the other implicit type mapper for Boolean from your import (`booleanColumnType => _`).

Comment: I broke out the mapper so I could reuse it: val YesNoMapper = MappedColumnType.base[Boolean, String](if(_) "y" else "n",_=="y")

Comment: Then I added it to the end like so: def is_good = column[Boolean]
  ("good",O.DBType("enum('y','n')"))(YesNoMapper)

Comment: Note: MappedColumnType requires Slick 2.0.0-M1 or later, for earlier versions just replace with MappedTypeMapper.